# Shell Script having trouble running commands in another app

Tags: shell, autosys

I am trying to make a script that auto adds "autosys" jobs to the machine so what it entails is it goes into the "autosys" editor and runs the commands.
I am facing an issue getting it to work as
Once it enters the JIL editor it stops executing the next commands and stands by there.

I think it's either because the jil editor is a different program shell script that just exits and so I tried using subshell using $() to run that but the problem remains. Looking to see if I am doing anything wrong or what am i missing.
It's supposed to be simple  but not sure what I am overlooking

```
echo script starts
$(Cd to source folder
Jil 
Insert job commands
To run in jil )
```

But what happens is once we run it

```
User@blah$ sh script.sh
User@blah$echo
User@blah$ cd 
<Blank space> 
<Blankspace>
```

Jil<> its editor and it does not execute the commands

Comment: We need a [mre] -- code we can run ourselves without changes to see the problem.

Comment: That said, clearly you should be feeding those statements on jil's stdin, not writing them as commands for the shell to run itself after jil exits. This is generally a job for a heredoc.

Comment: ...note that `$( )` is used when you want to capture the output of a program. It's basically never appropriate to have `$(` be the very start of a command -- that would make the shell responsible for running your program's _output_ as a command after an abbreviated/broken parsing stage basically eqivalent to how commands from variables are processed, thus having all the bugs described in [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). `var=$(...)` is much more reasonable, storing that output in a variable, or `othercommand "$(...)"`, making one command's output another's argument.

Comment: @XinCheng, most of your proposed edits were good ones, but please don't switch from the new code-formatting block style to the old style.

Comment: Thank you  the inputs i am  New to shell scripting i only use when needed so this knowledge is insightful . Regarding my question after digging around a bit i was able to run the commands with out a seperate shell. I  found the command on their page which said jil < file.jil  which allowed me to run it  directly from jil file instead of  individual commands.     Souce path ; jil < fil.jil solved it
Thanks for every ones input